# Calling multiple server actions asynchronously in webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, webforms

I've got an action on my website that requires me to check multiple web servers and aggregate the results.  Currently this is done synchronously against each web server in a `foreach` which can be slow depending on how responsive the web-server is.

What Id like to do is each request asynchronously and aggregate all the results when they are all complete.

My question is - with ASP.NET Webforms, what's the best way to do this? Is there anything I should avoid?

Each request could take 2 seconds so I'd like to kick them all off at the same time.

Comment: Which version of ASP.NET are you using?

Comment: See http://forums.asp.net/t/1331312.aspx/1

Comment: @JohnSaunders It's so, so much easier if you have access to .NET 4.5 though, hence Kiran's comment.

Comment: @pst: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45

Comment: @JohnSaunders That doesn't seem to have anything to do with "making it faster" :( This problem seems more suitable for TPL or similar parallelism, not necessarily across requests (e.g. reduce *other* response times under load).

Comment: After looking at the Async stuff in 4.5, im going to see if there is scrope to upgrade our project which is currently 4 to 4.5!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a good care for "standard" [asynchronous IO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+asynchronous+IO&submit=search) or "standard" threaded IO.

Where `T` represents `{time1, time2, ..}`, this would make the response `O(max(T))` instead of `O(sum(T))` - assuming no sequential dependencies or other bottlenecks.

This can be done either using either

**Asynchronous IO** - where the IO does not block the thread

- [async/await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) ("upcoming")
- or using the "old" [BeginX/EndX async pairs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86wf6409(v=vs.85).aspx) or other IAsync interfaces

or **Synchronous IO, but threaded** - where the IO does block an individual thread

- TPL in .NET4
- or "old manual" [threading/pooling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976073/recommendations-for-executing-net-httpwebrequests-in-parallel-in-asp-net) (linked post has same "requirement")

The .NET version used and the API available to get the external data plays a factor in which approach is [more] appropriate.

Comment: I think im going to go with the async/await pattern - it seems the best choice!

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery to make the asynchronous AJAX calls to the server.  However, I would use an ashx handler instead of a WebForm to process the AJAX calls on the server and send back the data to the client;  ashx handlers are more light weight than WebForms. Here is a quick tutorial on writing ASHX handlershttp://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx
Is this helping you?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET framework 4, you may use Task parallel library to achieve this. Assuming `GetDataFromServer` is the method you have to call for different servers, you may perform a piece of logic similar to the following logic to get data from all servers:

```
var d1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetDataFromServer("server1"));
var d2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetDataFromServer("server2"));
var d3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetDataFromServer("server3"));
var d4 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetDataFromServer("server4"));

TaskCoordinator.WhenAll(new Task[] {d1, d2, d3, d4});
```

The above step calls all the four methods asynchronously. It will wait for all of them to complete. Result of each operation is stored in `Result` property of the corresponding `Task` object. So, you can get the results using d1.Result, d2.Result and so on to perform your logic on the results obtained from the method calls.